# Net::HTTP.post_form cannot send parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, socket.io, net-http

Hi I'm using rails and socket.io in node.js 
What I'm trying to do is send a param in rails model using Net::HTTP.post_form
 and get the param in node.js file which is server.js

#### model send.rb

```
def self.push(userid)
   url = "http://socket.mydomain.com/push"
   res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(URI.encode(url)),data)
end
```

#### server.js

```
app.post('/push', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.param.userid)
});
```

#### req variable

```
req.ip =127.0.0.1
req.protocol= http
req.path = /push
req.host = socket.mydomain.com
req.param
```

I printed all the values but param always empty is there any solution for this? thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What is `data` in `res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(URI.encode(url)),data)`?

Comment: `data = Hash.new`  
`data[:userid] = "ebhwang"`  
  
by the way I solve this problem using url    

    `url = "http://socket.mydomain.com/push/#{userid}"`

    `app.post('/push/:userid', function (req, res) {  
      console.log(req.params.userid) 
     });`
    
but still req.param variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express you can retrieve values posted (HTTP POST) in an HTML form via req.body.searchText if you issue use app.use(express.bodyParser()); Notice that HTML form values come in req.body, not req.params.

Having said that, I am not sure how these values are submitted to the server when you use Socket.io rather than a "normal" HTTP POST on an HTML form.

I realize this is not an exact answer to your question, but wanted to mention how "normal" HTML form values are handled in case it helps and this was way to long to include as a comment.